# Audit users accessing site

Tags: access, auditing, ssom

I know analytic reports for visits and hits for a site, it doesn't show who all accessed and time. I want to audit users accessing site. Is there any way to do it using Server Object Model or other?

P.S: I know we have 'view' event in SharePoint audit. But it is pretty junk, showing lot of entries of viewing page and document for a single visit.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a custom List: Audit
- Setttings:

  [image]

  Restrict read access if required (the Site administrator can see all Items)
- Use JavaScript to write an Item to this List

Comment: thanks.. is there any other way without doing any javascript in site page? I can write customAuditEntry 'onLoad' of site page and get from audit entries. I don't want to track access using javascript. other way using powershell or CSOM?